# Doing a sphinx extension that folds sections in the body

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docutils, read-the-docs

I try to do an extension in Sphinx, the idea would be that the extension detects the title of sections and then transform them into a fold section, ie that sphinx render a title with a prefix button that helps to display or not the content of the section.

```
test_fold
=============

.. fold:: 

    * First Section 
        Hae duae provinciae bello quondam piratico catervis mixtae praedonum 
        a Servilio pro consule missae sub iugum factae sunt vectigales. 
        et hae quidem regiones velut in prominenti terrarum lingua positae 
        ob orbe eoo monte Amano disparantur.

    * Second Section
        Itaque tum Scaevola cum in eam ipsam mentionem incidisset, exposuit 
        nobis sermonem Laeli de amicitia habitum ab illo secum et cum altero 
        genero, C. Fannio Marci filio, paucis diebus post mortem Africani. 
        Eius disputationis sententias memoriae mandavi, quas hoc libro 
        exposui arbitratu meo; quasi enim ipsos induxi loquentes, ne 
        'inquam' et 'inquit' saepius interponeretur, atque ut tamquam 
        a praesentibus coram haberi sermo videretur.

    * Third Section
        Et interdum acciderat, ut siquid in penetrali secreto nullo citerioris 
        vitae ministro praesente paterfamilias uxori susurrasset in aurem, 
        velut Amphiarao referente aut Marcio, quondam vatibus inclitis, 
        postridie disceret imperator. ideoque etiam parietes arcanorum 
        soli conscii timebantur.
```

I began to write an extension like this :

```
from docutils.nodes import raw
from docutils.parsers.rst import Directive

FOLD = "*"
foldSize = len(FOLD)

def removeSpace(_str):
    if _str[0]==" ":
        return removeSpace(_str[1:])
    else:
        return _str

class FoldDirective(Directive):

   # this enables content in the directive
   has_content = True

   def run(self):

    titles = []
    mains = []
    newMain = ""

    #loop
    for indexInt in xrange(len(self.content)):

        #get
        string = self.content[indexInt]
        if indexInt>0:
            previousString = self.content[indexInt-1]
        else:
            previousString = ""

        #Check
        if len(string)>0:
            if string[0] == FOLD:
                titles.append(string[foldSize:])
                if indexInt>0:
                    mains.append(newMain)
                newMain = ""
            elif previousString[0] == FOLD:
                newMain = string
            else:
                newMain += string

    #append the last
    mains.append(newMain)

    #return
    return [raw('',"<table><tr>",format='html')]+map(
        lambda title,main:
        raw('',"<td><button/></td><td><div>"+str(title)+"</div><td>     <tr><td></td><td><div>"+str(main)+"</div></td></tr>",format='html'),
        titles,mains
    )+[raw('',"</tr></table>",format='html')]

def setup(app):
    app.add_directive('fold', FoldDirective)
```

But the problem here : 
- I don't know to bind the buttons with an onClick function that would make disappear the main on click.
- The main are just dropped in to a raw html, which is not optimal, because if they content also sub directives they would not be treated.
- The documentation of sphinx is really difficult to understand if I have to choose therefore in that case some calls of a nodes.General instances, but I don't know what precisely.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. We can help with a directive you've written, but we don't generally code from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You can learn how it is down in a cloud theme: http://pythonhosted.org/cloud_sptheme/cloud_theme_test.html#toggleable-section

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reading the documentation for [Sphinx extensions](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/index.html#dev-extensions) as well as looking at [this extension](https://github.com/Robpol86/sphinxcontrib-disqus/blob/master/sphinxcontrib/disqus.py) which changes the HTML markup with a directive for Disqus comments.